# Spring Cloud Contract issues retrieving stubs from Artifactory

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I have tests for two consumers and a producer working fine offline but the consumer tests fail when I change them for retrieving the stubs from Artifactory.

This is the code for working offline:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ContractTestConfiguration.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.mycompany:service-name:+:stubs"}, workOffline = true)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class MyContractTest
```

And this is for online:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ContractTestConfiguration.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.mycompany:service-name:+:stubs"}, repositoryRoot = "https://artifactory.companyname.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local")
@ImportAutoConfiguration(org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class MyContractTest {
```

I get this error:

```html
Exception occurred while trying to download a stub for group [com.mycompany] module [service-name] and classifier [stubs] in [remote0 (https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local, default, releases+snapshots)]
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mycompany.domain:service-name:jar:stubs:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I have looked in Artifactory and in https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local and the stubs jar appears there. I have done a mvn install of the producer and when I run the tests again I get this error "The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one".

I have also tried adding to the consumers a dependency on the stubs of the producer but I get similar errors. And I would prefer to avoid it because it would add a dependency with the specific version of the producer:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-name</artifactId>
    <classifier>stubs</classifier>
    <version>1.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I have added this to the POM file of the producer:

```xml
<spring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip>true</spring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>stub</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <attach>true</attach>
                <descriptor>${basedir}/src/assembly/stub.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And this is the content of the file stub.xml that is under src/assembly:

```xml
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>stubs</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**com/companyname/projectname/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**com/companyname/projectname/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/snippets/stubs</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/mappings</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources/contracts</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/contracts</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Any idea of what I am missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have looked in Artifactory and in https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local and the stubs jar appears there. I have done a mvn install of the producer and when I run the tests again I get this error "The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one".

This happens when you install a stub locally, then try to download it from artifactory but SHAs are different, so Aether (engine that downloads stubs) picks the local one. In this case we throw an exception cause you wanted to download the stub from a remote location and not take it from the local one.

> Exception occurred while trying to download a stub for group [com.mycompany] module [service-name] and classifier [stubs] in [remote0 (https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local, default, releases+snapshots)]
>   org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mycompany.domain:service-name:jar:stubs:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT

This looks like in Artifactory you had the entry in some Maven metadata that the latest jar is `1.6.0-SNAPSHOT` but the JAR is no longer there. Can you double check that it's actually there?

> I have also tried adding to the consumers a dependency on the stubs of the producer but I get similar errors. And I would prefer to avoid it because it would add a dependency with the specific version of the producer:

That only proves that you have something messed up with your artifactory / project settings. Do things still don't work if you hardcode versions?

UPDATE:

If your artifactory instance requires credentials or is behind a proxy you can use these values:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/v1.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerProperties.java#L72-L87

You can provide the `stubrunner.username`,  `stubrunner.password`,  `stubrunner.proxyHost` and `stubrunner.proxyPort`

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. For ensuring that I don't have problems from previous testings I have deleted the stubs jars from Artifactory, done another mvn deploy and checked that the new jars have been published in Artifactory. After that I have deleted the stubs jar of the local Maven repository and tried again to run the consumer tests.  I have now a different error, "Could not transfer artifact com.companyname:service-name:jar:stubs:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT from/to remote0 (https://artifactory.companyname.com/artifactory/artifacts-snapshot-local): connect timed out.

Comment: May it be that Aether cannot download the stubs jar because I have to specify somewhere the username and password of Artifactory? Or may it be that the proxy is blocking the access to it? I assumed that Aether uses the values of the file .m2/settings.xml , but I will look for info about it

Comment: When I hardcode the values and do a Maven -> Reimport from Intellij, the stubs get downloaded from Artifactory, and when I run the tests I get this error in the logs: "The artifact was found in the local repository but you have explicitly stated that it should be downloaded from a remote one". However if I just run the tests without a reimport I get a connection time out like if I hadn't harcoded the values

Comment: I've updated the answer with username / password and proxies setup

Answer (score 0):

Can `stubrunner.username` and `stubrunner.password` be provided in the `@AutoConfigureStubRunner` annotation? I have tried the following:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
 @AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.mycompany.myproj:myservice:+:stubs:8100",
    repositoryRoot = "http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local",
    properties = {"stubrunner.username=myusername", "stubrunner.password=mypassword"},
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE)
 @DirtiesContext
 class MyApiContractsVerificationTest {
     ...
 }
```

The credentials are correct, and the stubs are correctly generated and deployed into the remote Artifactory repository. The tests run fine if I configure them to look in the local .m2/repository (removing the "repositoryRoot and "properties" annotation args), but with the above configuration I get the following error:

```
Could not find metadata com.mycommany.myproject:myservice/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/myname/.m2/repository), 
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata com.mycommany.myproject:myservice/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote0 (http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local): **Unauthorized (401)**]
...
```

I do clean the local .m2/repository of the stubs before I run the tests with the remote mode enabled, so there is no conflict.

Am I incorrectly providing the username and password? Is something incorrect or missing in the configuration?

Comment: Hi, have you tried configuring also stubrunner.proxyHost and  stubrunner.proxyPort ? Deploying to Artifactory and reading from it is different, because the first one is done by Maven using the values of .m2/settings.xml and the second one is done by Aether using the settings that you write in your code

Comment: @rafaborrego: Thank you for your reply. I don't think our Artifactory is configured with a proxy. I wish the error message were a bit more detailed, providing a bit more context. Ugh...

Comment: As I step through the AetherStubDownloader code in the debugger, I see that everything but username and password is properly set on the StubRunnerOptions object passed to the constructor. The username and password properties are null. Instead they are set as custom values on the "properties" Map field, which, obviously, is not what's used as the connection credentials.  If I use externalized properties in "application-test.yml" (and add @ActiveProfiles("test") to the class) everything works. So, I guess there is no way to define the credentials via the annotation... This is fine.

Comment: Maybe not, I have defined them in the application.yml file like this:

stubrunner:
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  proxyHost: xxx
  proxyPort: xxx