# Spring Cloud Contract issues retrieving stubs from local repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to run the stub from my client app but getting below error -

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For groupId
>   [com.xx] artifactId [cdc-demo-server] and classifier
>   [stubs] the version was not resolved! The following exceptions took
>   place [org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could
>   not find metadata
>   com.xx:cdc-demo-server/maven-metadata.xml in local
>   (C:\Users\xx\.m2\repository)]

Actually, I am using a different m2 repo which the runner is unable to identify.

I tried setting the m2 repo path using `repositoryRoot = "C:/m2_repo/"` in `@AutoConfigureStubRunner` and also updating pom as

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <maven.repo.local>${settings.localRepository}</maven.repo.local>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

In my repo I can see a file `maven-metadata-local.xml` along with the stubs jar. Any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Cloud Contract issues retrieving stubs from Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513965/spring-cloud-contract-issues-retrieving-stubs-from-artifactory)

Comment: @Alien I don't think it's duplicate. I am facing this issue for local repo.

Comment: Are you sure your group & artifact ids are correct? I see that it's windows, maybe something's wrong with the `/` ? Might be a bug in contract.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak glad to see you answering this :) As per my observation the stub runner is not picking the different repo location even though I set the `repositoryRoot` property. Maven co-ordinates look ok.

Comment: Have you set `repositoryRoot` to a different location AND set `stubsMode` to `REMOTE` (or for 1.2 disabled `workOffline`) ?

Comment: repositoryRoot is `C:/m2_repo/` and `stubsMode` is `LOCAL`. If you need more input or code snippet please let me know

Comment: Change stubs mode to remote. Otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: But if I want to use stub from local repo why to change the mode to remote :-/

Comment: When I moved the artifact folder to `.m2` it worked! So somehow a different maven location was not picked up.